# Video Audio still plays when the parent div is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, webflow

when my video's parent element is hidden is still plays the audio of the video. I need the audio to stop playing, thank you! Also if you'd like to take a look at the actual website feel free to have a look: https://accela-6b408f29a6797bfc3f-ecd2f4351342a.webflow.io/

(P.S. You will only be able to view the video screen once every 45 minutes to please block cookies for this website if you'd like to see it multiple times)

(The video can be skipped by clicking "Skip Video" then the sound continues

This is the code used to display the video:

```js
 /*Idea: add listener for hover while playing show pause*/

var bunnyVideo = document.getElementById("bVideo");
var el = document.getElementById("playButton");
//var ey = document.getElementById("pauseButton");
var replay = document.getElementById("replayButton");

//Hide replay button at start
replay.style.visibility='hidden';
pauseButton.style.visibility='hidden';


function playPause() {
  replay.style.visibility='hidden';
  if (bunnyVideo.paused) 
  {
    bunnyVideo.play();
    el.className = "";
  } 
  else 
  {
    bunnyVideo.pause();
    el.className = "playButton";
  }
}

function playPauseControls() {
  replay.style.visibility='hidden';
  if (!bunnyVideo.paused) {
    el.className = "";

  } else {
     el.className = "playButton";
  }
}

function hideHoverPauseButton(){
   replay.style.visibility='hidden';
    if (!bunnyVideo.paused) {
      el.className = "";
    } else {
      el.className = "playButton";
    }
}

function showHoverPauseButton(){
   replay.style.visibility='hidden';
    if (!bunnyVideo.paused) {
      el.className = "pauseButton";
    } else {
      el.className = "playButton";
    }
}

function videoEnd() {
  replay.style.visibility='visible';
  el.className = "";
  bunnyVideo.setAttribute("controls","controls");
}

function showControls(){
  bunnyVideo.setAttribute("controls","controls");
}
function hideControls(){
  bunnyVideo.removeAttribute("controls","controls");
}

/*Google Analytics Tracker Function*/
/*Assuming you've already set up the Google Analytics script function on your webpage. This just activates a trigger event when the video plays.*/
/*function bunnyVideoView() {
     ga('send', 'event', { 
          'eventCategory': 'Bunny Video',
          'eventAction': 'play',
          'eventLabel': 'Bunny Video View'
     });
}*/

/* You can play with this to hide controls or not */
bunnyVideo.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
bunnyVideo.addEventListener("play", playPauseControls, false);
bunnyVideo.addEventListener("pause", playPauseControls, false);
bunnyVideo.addEventListener("mouseover", hideControls, false);
bunnyVideo.addEventListener("mouseout", hideControls, false);
bunnyVideo.addEventListener("mouseover", showHoverPauseButton, true);
bunnyVideo.addEventListener("mouseout", hideHoverPauseButton, true);
el.addEventListener("mouseover", showHoverPauseButton, true);
el.addEventListener("mouseover", hideControls, false);
replay.addEventListener("mouseover", hideControls, false);
bunnyVideo.addEventListener("ended", videoEnd, false);  
/*Google Analytics Tracker*/
/*bunnyVideo.addEventListener("play", bunnyVideoView, false);*/
```

```html
   <center>
  <div class="video-wrapper1">
    <video id="bVideo">
      <source src="https://github.com/intricate-rogue/AccelaFiles/blob/master/accela-video-withsound.mp4?raw=true
" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <div id="playButton" class="playButton" onclick="playPause()"></div>
   <div id="pauseButton" class="pauseButton" onclick="playPause()"></div> 
    <div class="replayButton" id="replayButton" onclick="playPause()"></div>
  </div>
  
</center>
```

Comment: so pause it when you hide it??

Comment: hey @epascarello yes I'd like help in Pausing it when it's hidden yes

Comment: so call pause like you do in other places??

Comment: maybe set it to not autoplay if that is the problem?

Comment: The autoplay is required as soon as they get to the website so I cannot stop this. I'm not sure how to "call pause" I'm not a developer and did not write this code so any assistance would be greatly appreciated